# JAVA SQL how do update column without erasing current value

Tags: java, oop, user-interface, methods

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String CardNumber = Card.getText();
        String CVV = LastThreeDigits.getText();
        String Exp = Expire.getText();
        String Amount = va.getText();
        String username = Username.getText();

        Customer c1 = new Customer(CardNumber, Exp, Amount, username);
        boolean validated = c1.VerifyCreditCard(CardNumber, CVV, Exp, Amount, username);

        if (validated) {
            try {
                String don = "Update Login set Funds= '" + Amount + "' where Username= '" + username + "' ";
                PreparedStatement man = connect.prepareStatement(don);

                man.executeUpdate();

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Updated"); `enter code here`
                AdminDashBoard dash = new AdminDashBoard();
                dash.show();
                frame.setVisible(false);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();

            }
        } else if (!(validated)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Missing fields");
        }
    }
```

I'm using this method to update a table with column funds. Whenever I put the value, it does update the table, however how do I make it so when it updates the fund it adds it to the current value? I'm very new to coding.

What I mean is if user puts the value as 10. It should show 10 in the database, and if the user wants to put say 20. The value in the database should be 30.

Comment: sorry for awful formating

Comment: Why don’t you just read the current value, set the new value in the code, then update the row. Or afaik, you can do set value = value + newValue where...

Comment: Could u go more in depth? Sorry I'm really new to coding, and struggling to understand certain aspects more than the others

Answer (score 0):

You can append it to the existing value:

```
Update Login set Funds = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(Funds) + Integer.parseInt('" + Amount + "')) where Username = '" + username + "' ";
```

Or a better solution, IMO, is to read in the current value, then add it in the code together, and just set the new value in your existing `set` statement.

Comment: String don = "Update Login set Funds = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(Funds)) + Integer.parseInt('" + amount + "')) where Username = '" + username + "' ";    like this?

Comment: @codeisnotf0rme - that looks like my post yes, so try it and see does it work. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: I'm getting this error: org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "(": syntax error)